# Ruby odd scenario opening a directory stored in a variable

Tags: ruby, file, directory

I've got a Ruby script which opens a directory and prints the contents to the screen:

```
rootDir = '/Users'
puts rootDir

Dir.foreach(rootDir) do |folder|
  next if folder == '.' or folder == '..'

  puts folder if(File.directory? rootDir+'/'+folder)

end
```

When I run this in terminal, I get the following error:

```
/Users
imager.rb:77:in `open': No such file or directory - /Users (Errno::ENOENT)
from imager.rb:77:in `foreach'
from imager.rb:77
```

Line 77 is the Dir.foreach line. But when I run the following code, it works perfectly:

```
rootDir = '/Users'
puts rootDir

Dir.foreach('/Users') do |folder|
  next if folder == '.' or folder == '..'

  puts folder if(File.directory? '/Users'+'/'+folder)

end
```

It seems when the folder path is stored in rootDir, it can't find the folder. Any ideas? /Users is not in the same directory as the script.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the solution just now. The folder /Users was read in from terminal, and stored in a file. When I read it in from the terminal, I did a .chomp, but when I stored it in a file, I kept the \n at the end. Reading it from the file put it back on the end. Whoops.